# Importing sqldump into docker-container

Tags: mysql, docker

I am trying to import a sqldump into a running MySQL Docker-Container with this command:

```
 sudo docker exec -i a2bdd4db352a /usr/bin/mysql -u username -ppassword --max_allowed_packet=1500M --default-character-set=utf8 database < /srv/Dump.sql
```

After a while getting these error:

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 979: MySQL server has gone away
read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer
```

Logs:

```
2017-12-07T09:44:21.099302Z 3 [Note] Aborted connection 3 to db: 'database' user: 'database' host: 'localhost' (Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes)
```

Tried to increase the max_allowed_package variable in my MySQL-Conf ---> Nothing changed - still the same error.

My Dump has a size of 16 GB.

Has anybody a idea - how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error says the particular row data has size more than 1500M, so try increasing  max_allowed_packet to higher value

For detailed info refer below link
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Problem was that i had increased this value but forget to comment in the special line for using my configuration in Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tried to increase the paramater `--max_allowed_packet=1500M` to `--max_allowed_packet=200000M` ?